# Evaluate a big expression.

Tags: integration, limits, definite-integrals

If:$$\lambda=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{1+x^3} ;$$

Then evaluate : $$ p=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\left( \frac{\prod_{r=1}^{n}\left(n^3+r^3\right)}{n^{3n}} \right)^{1/n} ;$$

EDIT: I have now ended upto $$lnp=\int_{0}^{1} \ln(1+t^3).dt$$

Now, we have to evaluate this using $\lambda$ , howsoever .

Comment: @ChristopherA.Wong I tried and even got a hint that it's going to turn into a definite integral . but was unable to solve.This is a previous year problem from IIT-JEE ( adm. exam for IIT India).

Comment: Answer is in terms of $\lambda$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, to evaluate $\lambda$, use partial fractions:

$$\frac{1}{1+x^3} = \frac{1}{3} \left ( \frac{1}{1+x} - \frac{x-2}{x^2-x+1} \right )$$

The second piece in the parentheses is more amenable to integration when expressed as follows:

$$\frac{x-2}{x^2-x+1} = \frac{x-1/2}{(x-1/2)^2+3/4} - \frac{3/2}{(x-1/2)^2+3/4}$$

Now, let

$$A = \int_0^1 \frac{dx}{1+x} = \log{2}$$

$$B = \int_0^1 dx \: \frac{x-1/2}{(x-1/2)^2+3/4} = \left[\log{\left[ \left(  x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+\frac{3}{4}\right]}\right]_0^1 = 0$$

$$C = \int_0^1 dx \: \frac{3/2}{(x-1/2)^2+3/4} = \sqrt{3} \left[\arctan{\left [ \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}} \left( x-\frac{1}{2}\right)\right]}\right]_0^1 = \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{3}}$$

Therefore

$$\lambda = \frac{1}{3} (A - B + C) = \frac{1}{3} \log{2} + \frac{\pi}{3 \sqrt{3}}$$

Now for the limit, which is evaluated by taking logs of both sides:

$$\log{p} = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{r=0}^n \log{\left(1+\frac{r^3}{n^3}\right)}$$

This is a Riemann sum, in the sense that

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{r=0}^n f \left(\frac{r}{n}\right) = \int_0^1 dx \: f(x)$$

Therefore

$$\begin{align}\log{p} &= \int_0^1 dx \: \log{(1+x^3)}\\ &= [x \log{(1+x^3)}]_0^1 - \int_0^1 dx \: \frac{3 x^3}{1+x^3}\\ &= \log{2} - 3 \int_0^1 dx \: \left ( 1 - \frac{1}{1+x^3}\right)\\ &= \log{2}-3 + 3 \lambda\\&= 2 \log{2}-3 + \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{3}}\\ \therefore p &= 4 e^{-(3 - \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{3}})}\end{align}$$

Comment: Please ...... NO :( ; We are given $\lambda$ and we have to use it to evaluate $P$

Comment: But then also great effort. I never even thought of ealuating this . as it was given. Ans in terms of $\lambda$

Comment: You were given $\lambda$ as an integral; you may either choose to evaluate it or not.  If you do not, then the result is just formal, isn't it?

Comment: nice work Ron.  I'll stop typing up what I had now :(

Comment: @muzzlator: why would you do that?  You may have a different insight?

Comment: Same process, same integration by parts.

Comment: You got it man! Answer given in same as 3rd last step $p=ln2-3-3\lambda$

Comment: @exploringnet: you mean $\log{p}$

Comment: And I all-together knew what Reimann sum is [ though not by name ].That's why i had ended up converting p into a definite integral.And yes. It's in terms of $lnp$

Comment: Was a good Question indeed. what say! got 2-3 concepts in it!

Comment: @exploringnet: well, as you say, it was for an IIT exam.  I can't imagine they make them easy.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  Take the log of the second expression

You'll get a Riemann sum expression which you can then use your value of $\lambda$ to solve.

Comment: Now, what is Reimann. And I explained above that i have changed it into a definite integral ( though not completely).

Comment: I'll give more details then, hold up.

Comment: please see my progress in question(editted)